# Simulate ASP.NET Page lifecycle

Tags: asp.net

I have an HttpHandler in which I want to render the HTML for some custom controls.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
Page p = new Page();
var customControl = new CustomControl { Data = data, Blah = blah };
p.Controls.Add(customControl );
context.Response.Write(customControl.RenderToString());
```

The problem is that customControl (and child controls thereof) needs to do stuff in the OnInit, OnLoad and OnPreRender methods.

I have tried manually calling this methods through helper methods but I get various errors.   My general problem is that I need the ASP.NET page lifecycle to run on the `p` variable.  Is there any way to get that to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>i haven't come to try this yet...</strike>
works for me!

based on [ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/10/22/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Cool-UI-Templating-Technique-to-use-with-ASP.NET-AJAX-for-non_2D00_UpdatePanel-scenarios.aspx)'s work,
[jim](http://www.jamesewelch.com/2008/07/11/how-to-render-a-aspnet-user-control-within-a-web-service-and-return-the-generated-html/) suggests
something like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(myPage, myTextWriter, false);
```

Comment: I think this is more or less what I did.  I'm no longer with that company so I can't go look at the code to check :|

Comment: all i can tell is that it works for me, and since i wasn't able to find any "better" solution it went into production - no problems so far.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Instead of an HttpHandler use a regular page...

Barring that, change your control to work a bit differently.

Comment: I have currently worked around by creating a dummy page and using `context.Server.Execute(url)`.  However, I with there was a way to run the page lifecycle on a page without created an .aspx and telling ASP.NET to run that file.

Comment: @tster: I'm not entirely sure what the purpose would be.  The PRIMARY difference between a generic handler (.ashx) and a regular page (.aspx) is that the former doesn't execute the full lifecycle.

Comment: @Chris Lively, The handler in question is being used by a custom WebControl and hence I cannot use a Page. Basically I have a custom control which needs to get some HTML to render using AJAX, and this handler is what processes the AJAX request.  The HTML is complex and based on another custom control which does a lot of things for me.

Comment: @tster: I guess I just don't understand why the AJAX request can't just go to a page (even if it's a different one) instead of a handler...

Comment: @Chris Lively, the AJAX request is coming from javascript packaged with a component in a separate project.  The handler is also in that separate project.  I don't want the handler to have to call a Page in the Web Application project because I don't want it to depend on the Web Application project.

Comment: @tster: Okay, I think I understand now. Thanks for the clarification.  Interesting problem though.

Comment: anyone a solution yet? got exactly the same problem. a page "embeds" content rendered on a remote side via a service-call, the service renders the control in question and delivers the markup. the only problem: the controls use e.g. the Unload event, which doesn't occur when i create a page from code and simply render the control